# How to add a specific value to all class instances?

Tags: c#, class

Right now I have the following code:

```
public class Argument
{
    public static readonly Argument ApiKey = new Argument("api_key", true);

    private string _key;
    private bool _required;
    private string _value;

    private Argument(string name, bool required)
    {
        _key = name;
        _required = required;
    }

    public void AddValue(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when I execute `ApiKeyInstance.AddValue("apikey");`, the value of this is added to all instances of the `ApiKey` Argument instance.

How can I complete this code to achieve what I want, or is there a better way to achieve this? What I'm thinking of right now is using a Singleton but if so, how can I add the specific value, without a reference in the code? (Something like `Argument arg = Argument.ApiKey; arg.AddValue("str");`)

Comment: `ApiKey` is static. There are no instances of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John notes in his comment, `ApiKey` is static, so the same value is shared across all object instances.

*Additionally*, it is marked `readonly`, which means that the `ApiKey` instance assigned cannot be changed once set, though you can modify properties of that instance if the `ApiKey` class so allows.  Such modifications would be visible to all instances of the `Argument` class.

Comment: Which practically means that if I call '*Argument.ApiKey.AddValue("apikey");*' this value is all through my code to say so? (Sorry for my lack of understanding atm)